# How to call outter class' constructor within the inner class

Tags: java, android

```
public class foo {
    class bar{
        public bar(String str) {
            this("hello", str);
        }
    }

    public foo(String a, String b) {
        System.out.println(a+","+b);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to call foo's constructor in bar?

Comment: you can access by creating object of outer class.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this :

```
public class foo {

    private String var1;//<<----------
    private String var2;//<<----------

    class bar {

        public bar(String str) {
            foo f = new foo(str, str);//<<----call your constructor 
        }
    }

    public foo(String a, String b) {
        System.out.println(a + "," + b);

        //set values to your attribute
        this.var1 = a;//<<------------set value 1
        this.var2 = b;//<<------------set value 2
    }
}
```

Comment: There are some variables in foo and I must set them by calling foo's constuctor in bar.

Comment: can you provide an example about this so we can understand more @NaimBerkTumer ?

Comment: @NaimBerkTumer I think you are confusing inner classes and subclasses. What you want to do is feasible with a subclass, not with an inner class.

Comment: you can check my answer now, hope this is what you want to do @NaimBerkTumer

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to fetch user id by username from firebase db, then with the user id, get the user information from database and set them to the current instance. What you've written creates a new instance but I want it to set variables of current instance.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this

```
      foo obj = new foo("hello", "world");
```

Answer (score 0):

[Link to the Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

> An instance of InnerClass can exist only within an instance of
>   OuterClass and has direct access to the methods and fields of its
>   enclosing instance.
>
> To instantiate an inner class, you must first instantiate the outer
>   class. Then, create the inner object within the outer object with this
>   syntax:
>
> OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass();

Constructor of foo accepts 2 arguments, so you have to provide them to create its object.
You can also create an empty constructor and then use it in the following way

// Instantiating the outer class

foo outer = new foo();

// Instantiating the inner class

foo.bar inner = outer.new bar("world");